# Program is not accepting second string and giving output directly

Tags: c, string, xcode, fgets

Here I want to compare two strings in `case2`.  `case 1` works well but when I go to `case 2` it's not asking for second string input and directly prints "Both strings are different"[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2J6L.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 20

int main ()
{
    char str1[size],str2[size];
    int operation,error=0,i=0;
    printf("Enter String: ");
    fgets(str1, size, stdin);
    do {
        printf("1.Copy\n2.Compare\n3.Exit\nWhich operation you want to do:");
        scanf("%d",&operation);
        switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                for (int i=0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                    str2[i] = str1[i];
                }
                printf("First string: %s\n",str1);
                printf("Second string: %s\n",str2);
                break;
            
            default:
                printf("Error");
                break;
        
            case 2:
                printf("Enter second string: ");      // it's not executing (Not takin input) and directly i get o/p of line 39
                fgets(str2, size, stdin);
                for (i=0; str2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                    if (str1[i] != str2[i]) {
                        error++;
                    }
                }
                if (error == 0) {
                    printf("Both strings are same.\n");
                }
                else
                    printf("Both strings are not same.\n");
                break;
        }
    

    } while (operation != 3);
}
```

Comment: Don't mix `fgets()` with `scanf()`.  Avoid `scanf()`.  `fgets()` reads a _line_.  `scanf("%d")` leaves the trailing `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `scanf` leaves behind a dangling newline character `\n` it causes the fgets to not wait for the input from the user. Try flushing the input buffer by using `getchar`.

**Update:** Added loop to remove all the characters which are skipped by the `scanf` but can be entered by the user like extra white spaces after the number.

```c
...
do {
        printf("1.Copy\n2.Compare\n3.Exit\nWhich operation you want to do:");
        scanf("%d",&operation);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        switch (operation) {
...
```

Reference: [faq.cprogramming.com](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284392&answer=1044873249)

Comment: Thank you so much for investing your time and helping me in silly problems. I got it clear :)

Comment: @Anamay Glad, it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your strings are lines, scanf() is not a good choice except for getting the integer value, and to clean the buffer of everything after that (might be all sorts of junk, never trust a user), do a fgets into str2.  Your new lines will compare, too, if they are identical.  You should also test the return from scanf is 1, saying you got a number!  What if a user types in 'x' as the number?  If you want to ask again, you need to clean the junk out of the buffer.  Remember that, since you have 'cooked' input, nothing is sent until the user hits enter, so you always need to deal with the new line character.  If all you do is scanf in numbers, scanf will got through an new line as white space seeking a digit, but you are doing mixed string and number input.

You need to compare a null to mis-compare if one string is a prefix of the other, so in 'for' test 'i < size' but break out of the loop if both strings have a null at the same point ( !str1[i] && !str2[i] ) or on the first miscompare (setting error).  There is no point in comparing past the first miss!  In the prefix case, the null mis-compares some other char value.

Since trailing spaces are part of your string, you might print them in single quotes (after removing the new line).

Comment: Yes sir Thanks for your response, I got it clear :) Thank you